# Is it possible to use Firebase "onWrite" events with client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, visual-studio-cordova

I am building a Cordova mobile app for Android and want to add an event listener to my client-side JavaScript such that a function is called whenever data is written to a section of my firebase database. I know this can be done in node using firebase-functions and the onWrite events. However in trying to follow the getting started documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) for using the firebase CLI, I have hit a roadblock in that I am trying to write client side code, so I cant use

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

because of the "require". I am looking at work-arounds for this like using requirejs but I'm not sure this is appropriate as I don't know which scripts I am trying to load in order for the fire-base functions to work. Is there a better way to do this ? Or is it not appropriate to be trying to use firebase-functions with client side java-script in the first place?

Inexperienced developer so I was hoping there was an easier way then having to make a separate project to use as a server, and a better way than having the client ping the firebase database every second to see if it has updated. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with listeners from the firebase client SDK? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `firebase-functions` on the client.  It's only for use with backend code deployed to Cloud Functions.

Client code using the Firebase SDK doesn't have the same capabilities as Cloud Functions triggers.  That is to say, you can't write client code that triggers the same way as a Realtime Database trigger.  You will need to write your client code using the capabilities offered by the client SDK, which involves setting up listeners at locations of the database you're interested in.

Comment: Doug, isn't a value event listener from the JavaScript SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) a possible solution for the OP requirement? Thx

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Only if you're comfortable getting the **entire** set of all data at the location, followed by updates of **every** change **anywhere** in that set.  That's not even close to what Cloud Functions triggers do.  `child_added` events are closer, but they still require you to consume all children at the location.  For some data sets, this simply does not scale.